# How to get the created Team Uri?

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

So I'm creating Microsoft.Graph Group and Team. And it seems that they are created successfully. The problem is that I cannot get created team Uri.

My Rest request with new group id looks like this:

```
RestClient client = new RestClient("https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/" + groupId + "/endpoints");
RestRequest request = new RestRequest(Method.GET);
request.AddHeader("Authorization", accessToken);
IRestResponse response = await client.ExecuteTaskAsync(request, new CancellationToken());
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS Teams generates the link (`Get Link to team` menu action) in the following format:

```
https://teams.microsoft.com/l/team/19%3a{channel-id}%40thread.skype/conversations?groupId={group-id}&tenantId={tenant-id}
```

Once the team is created, `channel-id` could be retrieved via endpoint:

```
GET: https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/groups/{group-id}/channels
```

To determine `tenant-id` you could refer [Find your Office 365 tenant ID](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/find-your-office-365-tenant-id-6891b561-a52d-4ade-9f39-b492285e2c9b) 
article.

**Example**

```
static string GetTeamLink(string groupId, string channelId,string tenantId = null)
{
    return
            String.Format("https://teams.microsoft.com/l/team/19%3a{0}%40thread.skype/conversations?groupId={1}&tenantId={2}",
                channelId.Replace("-", string.Empty),
                groupId,
                tenantId);
}
```